# Send and receive a large json object in http

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream, jsonstream

I have a configuration is such a way that.

Client application server running on Nodejs with expressjs.
API server is running on Nodejs with expressJs and I am using postgresql database.

When my client has requested data from api server, api server is throwing an error

```
"*Error is  RangeError: Invalid string length*".
```

I guess the reason for it is, api is tying to respond to client with an extremely large array of Json objects, which it has fetched from database.

Now my question is, How can I send such an extremely large Json object in http response? And if sent successfully, how can I handle it at the client side?

I came across JSONStream module. But, I couldn't find a good example which I can pick a implement in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**I think BodyParser will help..**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    parameterLimit: 100000,
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true
  }));
```

*This will increase the size of json over http requests and response*

You can also check:-

```
const fs = require('fs');
const server = require('http').createServer();

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  const src = fs.createReadStream('./big.file');
  src.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(8000);
```

Ref- [Freecodecamp link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93)

Answer (score -4):

Whenever we have to deal with larger data and we are facing issues due to it, in such scenarios data should always be fetched in chunks, rather than loading all data at once.
So in your scenario, I suggest you to load data in parts.

Comment: I cannot take this is an answer. My question is how can I send such a large json object in http response. If you suggest to send it in chunks, how can I divide it in to chunks and send in the response and in the same way, how can I get the same data on the client side in the same order? Any example is much appreciated.

Comment: Please stick to solutions instead of absurd suggestions. All systems are not in test mode to allow modifications.